# Why would a MySQL database "go away" during a SQLAlchemy query?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, mod-wsgi

I am writing a simple Flask WSGI web-application with a "User" table and using SQLAlchemy. When retrieving a user from this table as an object, the following error occurs:

```
OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away') 
[SQL: u'SELECT users.uid AS users_uid, users.username AS users_username, users.fullname AS users_fullname, users.password AS users_password, users.score AS users_score, users.totalattempted AS users_totalattempted, users.totalcorrect AS users_totalcorrect, users.settings AS users_settings \\nFROM users \\nWHERE users.uid = %s \\n LIMIT %s'] [parameters: (11, 1)]
```

For my login session management, I use the login_manager load user method:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(uid):
    return get_user_by_uid(uid)
```

This then calls my `get_user_by_uid(uid)` method:

```
def get_user_by_uid(uid):
    uid = int(uid)
    return session.query(User).filter(User.uid == uid).first()
```

The purpose for the `get_user_by_uid(uid)` method is to accept a user's ID, and return it as an object to be easily worked with.
Is the `OperationalError` caused by a fault in my query logic, or is it a problem with my actual MySQL server?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your mysql server local ? Does it occurs in another environment ?

Comment: @Cyrbil Yes - The server is local. I probably should also note that the server will execute queries a portion of the time, but I can't seem to find a correlation between this error, and query activity beside these trace-backs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

MySql server does that if there isn't a lot of activity

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html for all possible solutions